# Why am I not able to return the value of this specific key in the customers object?

Tags: javascript

Should return true but it's undefined and I don't know why.

```
function coffeeLoverExtended(customer){
  for (var key in customer) {
    return customer[key]['enjoysCoffee'];
  }
}

var customer001 = {
  name: "John Riley",
  ticketNumber: "A01",
  enjoysCoffee: true
};

console.log(coffeeLoverExtended(customer001)); //true
```

Comment: what do you want?

Comment: Putting a `return` statement in the middle of a `for` loop like that does not make sense. The `return` will exit the function immediately on the first iteration of the loop.

Comment: unless you want to return early, but we can safely assume that is not the case here. However: if you want to iterate over an object, you can't use `for ... of...`, you can only use that with iterables, and objects are not iterables. So, maybe have a look at `Object.entries`. Followed by the fact that `key` is _already_ going to be that `enjoysCoffee` property, so really: it's time to take a good, modern, tutorial on JS and how to do things in it, because you're not getting the basics right, and this is not the place to learn the basics.

Comment: I want to return the value of the key enjoysCoffee which should be true

Comment: You're checking `customer001["name"].enjoysCoffee` strings don't have an enjoysCoffee property.

Comment: well De C answered your question

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is looping over an object `customer` and getting key one by one. `key` contains the property in `customer` object. So what `customer[key]['enjoysCoffee']` means `get me the enjoysCoffee property from customer[key]` where key is one of the property of `customer` object.

There is no property `enjoysCoffee` of `customer[enjoysCoffee]` object. That's why it is returning `undefined`.

If you are trying to get the value of the `enjoysCoffee` property of an object `customer`. then it should be `customer["enjoysCoffee"]`;

```js
function coffeeLoverExtended(customer) {
  return customer["enjoysCoffee"];
}

var customer001 = {
  name: "John Riley",
  ticketNumber: "A01",
  enjoysCoffee: true,
};

console.log(coffeeLoverExtended(customer001)); //true
```

> You've to use `.` or `[]` to access the property of an object. It would be same if you would have written `customer["enjoysCoffee"]` or `customer.enjoysCoffee`

**Below is nested object example**

```js
function coffeeLoverExtended(customer) {
  // return customer.enjoysCoffeeObj["enjoysCoffee"];
  // or
  // return customer["enjoysCoffeeObj"].enjoysCoffee;
  // or
  // return customer["enjoysCoffeeObj"]["enjoysCoffee"];
  // or
  return customer.enjoysCoffeeObj.enjoysCoffee;
}

var customer001 = {
  name: "John Riley",
  ticketNumber: "A01",
  enjoysCoffeeObj: {
    enjoysCoffee: true,
  },
};

console.log(coffeeLoverExtended(customer001)); //true
```

All above return statement returns `true`.

Comment: or `customer.enjoysCoffee`